# Create dynamic buttons in a grid layout - Create a magic square UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, 2d

I'm supposed to create a magic square in 2D using Windows Forms Application. It should look like this:

[image: Image of 3x3 magic Square with numbers and grid shown.]

However, the user should be able to decide the size of the square (3x3, 5x5, 7x7, etc). I already wrote the code in a Console Application, but I don't know how to add the 2D graphics.

Somebody already asked this question ([How do I put my result into a GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817938/how-do-i-put-my-result-into-a-gui)), and one of the answers was to use `DataGridView`, but I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for, since I can't make it look like the picture.

Any ideas or advice?

Comment: you can use a `TableLayoutPanel` and add buttons to the panel dynamically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and add buttons to panel dynamically.

If you don't need interaction with buttons, you can add `Label` instead.

**Create square dynamically:**

```
public void CreateSquare(int size)
{
    //Remove previously created controls and free resources
    foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(item);
        item.Dispose();
    }

    //Create TableLayoutPanel
    var panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
    panel.RowCount = size;
    panel.ColumnCount = size;
    panel.BackColor = Color.Black;

    //Set the equal size for columns and rows
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        var percent = 100f / (float)size;
        panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, percent));
        panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, percent));
    }

    //Add buttons, if you have your desired output in an array
    //you can set the text of buttons from your array
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            var button = new Button();
            button.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            button.Font = new Font(button.Font.FontFamily, 20, FontStyle.Bold);
            button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

            //you can set the text of buttons from your array
            //For example button.Text = array[i,j].ToString();
            button.Text = string.Format("{0}", (i) * size + j + 1);
            button.Name = string.Format("Button{0}", button.Text);
            button.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            //If you need interaction with buttons
            button.Click += b_Click;
            panel.Controls.Add(button, j, i);
        }
    }
    panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(panel);
}
```

**If you need interaction with buttons**

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    //Instead put your logic here
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You clicked {0}", button.Text));
}
```

As an example, you can call

```
CreateSquare(3);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly for a 3x3 square. However, when the size is different (5x5, 7x7) I get different results. The "for loop" seems okay, so I don't know why I'm getting that output.

Comment: My bad. It displays the numbers correctly, I just had to make the window bigger to see the whole number (instead of seeing "24" I would only see "2"). Thanks again!

Comment: @Jack You are welcome, Yes, you can make window larger or make the font smaller :)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info =)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Form and add a TableLayoutPanel with this property

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = Color.Gold;
```

and this is the result

[image]

When you create Row and Column, to fit correctly set the percentage in this way:

[image]

After this you can add a Button or Label in each square.

[image]