# Easiest way to display 2dimensional array of values on buttons

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am looking for optymalize code with displaying 2dimensional array of values on buttons.
I have created grid of buttons like that:
http://screenshot.sh/m2eZscO4i0fXq
and I am actually displaying values of array on this buttons using this code:

```
button1.Text = board.gameBoard[0, 0].getValue().ToString();
button2.Text = board.gameBoard[0, 1].getValue().ToString();
button3.Text = board.gameBoard[0, 2].getValue().ToString();
button4.Text = board.gameBoard[0, 3].getValue().ToString();
button5.Text = board.gameBoard[1, 0].getValue().ToString();
...
button15.Text = board.gameBoard[3, 2].getValue().ToString();
button16.Text = board.gameBoard[3, 3].getValue().ToString();
```

Is there easier way to do that? It's working now (http://screenshot.sh/mMDP9pvcC7WOk), but it isn't the best way to do this thing I think. Can somebody show me how do that better?

Comment: You may find this post useful: [How to create a magic square using Windows Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968993/how-to-create-a-magic-square-using-windows-forms)

Comment: Yeah, this is great. I wasn't looking long enough :D This is better solution than below I think. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your buttons dynamically and during creating put the text what you want to `Button.Text`.

It will be something like:

```
// array of your buttons (it's not necessary)
var buttons = new Button[4,4];

void SomeMethod()
{
    for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
    for(var y = 0; y < 4; y++)
        {
            var newButton = new Button();
            // put your text into the button
            newButton.Text = board.gameBoard[x, y].getValue().ToString();
            // set the coordinates for your button
            newButton.Location = new Point(someCoordinateX, someCoordinateY);

            // store just created button to the array
            buttons[x, y] = newButton;

            // add just created button to the form
            this.Controls.Add(newButton).
        }
    }
}
```

then, use this method somewhere on initialization step to create and initialize your buttons. The `buttons` array could be used lately if you will need to modify your buttons somehow.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hmm.. It should work, thanks. Values and some properties of buttons will be changed each time after pressing key, so I will create a class for that.

Comment: In that case you can use created button array to handle button changes

Comment: TableLayoutPanel will be the better choice I guess because I can easy change whole Panel properties too.