# Add controls to a form to fill it

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I have X number of buttons to add to my Form programmatically;

What I would like is that all the controls have the same size and that they fill the form completely depending on the form size, for example with 4 buttons :

[image]

9 buttons :

[image]

Comment: And what do you expect to happen if the user resizes the form?

Comment: @Steve the user cannot resize the form :-)

Comment: OK, who's stopping you? What's the problem? Are you asking how to create controls, or did you forget what the division operator looks like? It's this one: `/`.

Comment: [How to create a magic square using Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968993/how-to-create-a-magic-square-using-windows-forms)

Answer (score 4):

To layout controls you can use a `TableLayoutPanel`

```
var tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel
{
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    RowCount = 2,
    ColumnCount = 2
};

tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50));
tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50));
tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50));
tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50));

tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });

yourForm.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);
```

It will also keep the aspect if you resize the form.