# c# - how can I handle the click event of controls created dynamically within a loop

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, dynamic, controls

I'm looking for some advice on how to add click event handlers to labels that have been created created dynamically within a loop.

I've searched for click event handlers on dynamically created controls but this always comes back with single controls that aren't within an array.

example of code:

```
                //create an array of 16 labels
                Label[] label = new Label[16];

                //loop through the array of labels
                for (int i = 0; i < label.Length; i++)
                {
                    label[i]        = new Label();              //create new label
                    label[i].Name   = "lbl" + i.ToString();     //give the label a name
                    label[i].Text   = "label " + i.ToString();  //give the label text
                }
```

Any help and advice on this would be great, thanks!

Comment: [Dynamic Button Creation - How to create a magic square using Windows Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33969228/3110834)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a handler:

```
label[i].Click += HandleLabelClick;

void HandleLabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that you can determine *which* label was clicked by using the `sender` argument:

```
void HandleLabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label = (Label) sender;
    if (label.Text == "this or that") { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Also it worth to say something about sender parameter.

Comment: Pretty simple! Thanks mate, I'll give it a try today!