# C# winforms add controls to dynamic created tabpages

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, tabcontrol

I have problem when i want to add controls to dynamic created tabpages. My software is POS system for restaurants. My idea is first create restaurant regions and regions has diferent number of the desks. Example: Region for diner have 15 desks, caffe bar region has 22 desks. Somthing like category and products in this case regions has desks. So to do that i use `tabcontrol` component! All `tabpages` is region name and tabpage content must be desks showed as `buttons`...

All regions and desks is stored in the `MySql` database.

So if tab_1 (Region #1) is selected as content loop all desks `buttons` on page.

My code all time return just one desk but i have 10 desks for region 1..

**Code for listing regions:**

```
private void RegionList()
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default["connectionstring"].ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM regions";
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
                    string name = reader["name"].ToString();
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);

                    tabPage.Name = "tab_" + id;
                    tabPage.Text = name;

                    foreach (var desk in DeskList(id))
                    {
                        tabPage.Controls.Add(desk);
                    }
                    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            conn.Close();
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And here is code for listing desks on specific region:

```
private List<Button> DeskList(int regionID)
{
    List<Button> desks = new List<Button>();

    try
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default["connectionstring"].ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM desks WHERE region_id = @id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", regionID);

                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Button btn = new Button();
                    string name = reader["name"].ToString();

                    btn.Text = name;
                    btn.Name = "desk_" + reader["id"];
                    btn.Size = new Size(100, 60);

                    desk.Add(btn);

                }
                reader.Close();
            };
            conn.Close();
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return desks;
}
```

So when i loop this i get just in all regions only 1 desk but correct result. All regions has min 10 desks. What i do wrong? Maybie my appoarch is wrong

Comment: It is possible that all of the Button objects are created on the UI but they are probably all stacked on top of each other because there is no location set on anything (unless the caller of `DeskList` does all this)

Comment: Does DeskList(id) return a list of 10 elements?

Comment: Yes problem is on location. Buttons are just stacked now when i add location work good

Comment: @Ivan Great. Please mark as answered if my post helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the previous statement regarding the placement of the buttons is probably the problem. Try adding the following which will change the placement of each button.

```
        int i = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            string name = reader["name"].ToString();

            btn.Text = name;
            btn.Name = "desk_" + reader["id"];
            btn.Size = new Size(100, 60);
            btn.Location=new Point(100, 100+i);

            desk.Add(btn);
            i += 10;
        }
```

Comment: You can use a `TableLayoutPanel` to arrange controls simply. [(Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33969228/3110834)