# Adding dynamic controls to TableLayoutPanel in .NET windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I want to dynamically add controls to a panel when a button is clicked. But I want to organize the positions. For example I want to have two textboxes side by side equal in width taking the equal space of panel. See the picture below.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, when the button is clicked, controls will be added. But I am having problem with using TableLayoutPanel. See my code below.

```
private void btnAddOption_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
            tb1.Text = "Cell 1";
            TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
            tb2.Text = "Cell 2";


            TableLayoutPanel rowLayout = new TableLayoutPanel();
            rowLayout.ColumnCount = 2;
            rowLayout.RowCount = 1;

            //want to add tb1 to cell 1 and tb2 to cell 2 of TableLayoutPanel         

            panelFoodOptions.Controls.Add(rowLayout);

        }
```

As you can see in my code, I commented what I want to do. These are my issues.

I tried this

```
rowLayout.Controls.Add(tb1);
rowLayout.Controls.Add(tb2);
```

So above way does not work. So I tried a way to get the cell of layout. But I am having a problem. See the picture below.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I have to pass child control to get the cell. But I haven't even added a control to the cell. I want to add the control to the cell getting its respective position. How can I add control to the cell I want?

Comment: [How to create a magic square using Windows Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968993/how-to-create-a-magic-square-using-windows-forms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the [`Controls.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he3sxc2a(v=vs.110).aspx) method and specify column and row for the control:

```
rowLayout.Controls.Add(tb1, 0, 0);
rowLayout.Controls.Add(tb2, 0, 1);
```

Comment: @WaiYanHein your welcome, next time remember to check overloads for the method you are using :)