# TableLayoutPanel - resize each cell on resizing parent control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm working on a control, which contains a `TableLayoutPanel`. 
The panel contains X rows and Y columns - where each cell is the same size.
Each cell contains a `Control`
When the parent controls is being resized, I want each cell to be resized as well, and keep the same size to each other.

I've tried to set the `Controls'` `Anchor` when added to the cell:

```
control.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top |
                 AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```

But this only makes the bottom row and the right most column expand.

Answer (score 2):

Using designer or code, you can set `SizeType` of the columns and rows to `Percent` and assign same percentage value for their size. Also set `Dock` property of your controls to `Fill`.

For example:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
for (var i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; i++)
{
    var percent = 100f / (float)tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount;
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, percent));
}
for (var i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount; i++)
{
    var percent = 100f / (float)tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, percent));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this was a great help.
But there is something odd going on: The last row, and the last column is just a tiny bit bigger than the other rows / columns? if I set the SizeType to Absolute, they will be the same size, but will not resize.

Comment: You're welcome. Take a look at an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33969228/3110834). I couldn't reproduce the problem which you mentioned in comments.