# Add rows to TableLayoutPanel at a given Index

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have TableLayoutPanel and adding rows dynamically. How can I insert the rows with controls at a specific index?

```
private void AddRowstoTableLayout()
{
  for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 5; cnt++)
  {
    RowStyle newRowStyle = new RowStyle();
    newRowStyle.Height = 50;
    newRowStyle.SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;

    Label lbl1 = new Label();
    lbl1.Text = "label-" + (cnt + 1);

    TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
    t1.Text = "text-" + (cnt + 1);

    Label lblMove = new Label();
    lblMove.Text = "Move-" + (cnt + 1);
    lblMove.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(dy_MouseDown);

    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Insert(0, newRowStyle);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl1, 0, cnt); //correct

    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(t1, 1, cnt); //correct
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblMove, 2, cnt); //correct
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount += 1;
  }
}
```

I tried

```
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Insert(0, newRowStyle);
```

but no luck

Comment: [Create dynamic buttons in a grid layout - Create a magic square UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33968993/3110834)

Comment: Don't use a TableLayoutPanel where a DataGridView is more appropriate.

Comment: Above is just a sample code. My requirement is too complex which cannot be handled using DataGridView. So I am forced to use TableLayoutPanel

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function out of the box.
The way is to add a row to your TableLayoutPanel. Then move all controls that are positioned in rows greater equal to your desired row index in a rowindex higher than their current position.
Here how you can do that:

```
void InsertTableLayoutPanelRow(int index)
{
    RowStyle newRowStyle = new RowStyle();
    newRowStyle.Height = 50;
    newRowStyle.SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;

    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Insert(index, newRowStyle);
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
    foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
    {
        if (tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(control) >= index)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(control, tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(control) + 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not able to remove a row at given position. How can I remove it

Comment: @sangamesh Your question was how to insert a row in a specific index. Why do you want to remove a row? Or is it another question?

Comment: Yes. Its another question

Comment: @sangamesh Then you have either change the context and title of your question or mark this question as answered and open a new one. This will help other people if they refer to your question in the future.