# WinForms FlowLayoutPanel alignment problem

Tags: c#, winforms, button, flowlayoutpanel

When I click on a button in my Floqlayoutpanel they should hide at the place where I clicked on them. But instead they disappear and all the other buttons move.

They should hide at their place

[image: They should hide at their place]

But this is what happens

[image: But this is what happens]

How I create my Buttons:

```
 private void CreateButton()
    {
        int buttonIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Name = $"Button_{buttonIndex}";
            button.Width = 100;
            button.Height = 100;
            button.Click += OnButtonClick;
            button.BackgroundImage = BackSideImage();

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);

            buttonIndex++;
        }
    }
```

How I hide my Buttons:

```
private void CompareCards()
    {
        if (clickedCards.Count >= 3)
        {

                if (clickedCards[0].PairIndex == clickedCards[1].PairIndex)
                {
                    clickedCards[0].Button.Hide();
                    clickedCards[1].Button.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                   clickedCards[0].Button.BackgroundImage = BackSideImage();
                   clickedCards[1].Button.BackgroundImage = BackSideImage();
                }

                clickedCards.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are looking for `TableLayoutPanel`, for example take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33968993/3110834).

Comment: They don't move, they flow..

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've tried it with a TableLayoutPanel but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hiding your button, you can make it invisible like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            var button = new Button
            {
                Name = "Test-" + x,
                Text = "Test-" + x,
                Width = 100,
                Height = 100
            };

            button.Click += OnButtonClick;
      flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Instead of this...
        //((Button)sender).Hide();

        //Do this...
        var button = ((Button) sender);
        button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        button.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = BackColor;
        button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = BackColor;
        button.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = BackColor;
        button.Text = string.Empty;
        button.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When someone can use a `TableLayoutPanel` why do they may want to use such a trick?!

Comment: Because it answers OP's problem of why his Buttons disappear, not what the most efficient/cleanest answer is.

Comment: @LeonidasFett I've tried it with your solution and it works so I thank you very much. In Germany we call this "Ehrenmann".

Comment: War mir eine Ehre, Man! :)